# Trigger on INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a simple question. Ive got a trigger to insert the values into another Database

So for example if there are two values and the trigger is checking the value in `Table A` and inserting into `Table B`

So here is the code

```
-- Trigger DDL Statements
USE `db`;
DELIMITER //

CREATE
DEFINER=CURRENT_USER()
TRIGGER `db`.`AFTER_INSERT_A`
AFTER INSERT ON `db`.`a`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

    IF NEW.val!= NULL
    THEN

        UPDATE b SET dateRemove=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE val=NEW.val;

        INSERT INTO b (val) VALUES(NEW.val) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE dateRemove=NULL, dateUpdate=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

    END IF;
END//
```

The trigger dosent even throw any errors. And i have no values in B

My Insert is

```
INSERT INTO a (val) VALUES(`test`) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE dateUpdate=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Has any one got any ideas. Ive tried creating two triggers one `INSERT`and the other `UPDATE`, Ive changed the `AFTER` to `BEFORE` and my table `b` still got nothing. Any ideas thanks in advance

Comment: Great question, and getting to be an oldie.  So, what if you want to get both OLD.val and NEW.val while inside the trigger?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The trigger to be run on a query such as

```
INSERT INTO table (x, y, z) VALUES('x', 'y', 'z') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE x=VALUES(x);
```

must always be run on a `BEFORE INSERT` Trigger.

Comment: I know this is old, but do you have an proof that this is true?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps instead of

```
NEW.val!= NULL
```

you need

```
NEW.val IS NOT NULL
```

A value is never equal to null, and it is never not equal to null.