# How can I generate a unique number to a repeating row based on actual row number in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have data that has to be dumped into a mysql table. I am depending on a Bill_Number to identify the records. But for few records, the billing number is same; it is because either the customer returned it or cancelled it or something.

Now I want to generate some key for these transactions.

For example, when an ID '123456' appears first time, I want to give it a key '98765'. When the same ID 123456 comes again, I want to give it a key '98765-1' and so on.

Comment: I think you want to use on duplicate key clause on your insert statement as shown [on prior stack article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162767/trigger-on-insert-on-duplicate-key) or [in mySQL docs:](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)  you'll have to use some string logic to account for -1 vs -2 vs etc...  when - is in string add 1 to numeric value to right of - ...assuming only - exist in duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here ist your Answer. Now you can insert every Row and field in a new Table

```
MariaDB [tmp]> select * from example;
+----+--------+
| id | billnr |
+----+--------+
|  1 | 6789   |
|  2 | 1234   |
|  3 | 6789   |
|  4 | 6789   |
|  5 | 2345   |
|  6 | 1234   |
+----+--------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [tmp]> SELECT
    ->   @nr:=IF(@lastid = e.billnr , @nr:=@nr+1 ,0) AS recno,
    ->   @lastid:=billnr AS last_type,
    ->    concat(billnr,IF(@nr > 0, concat('-',@nr),'')) AS new_billnr,
    ->     e.*
    ->   FROM `example`e,
    ->   (SELECT @lastid:=0, @nr:=0) tmp
    -> ORDER BY billnr;
+-------+-----------+------------+----+--------+
| recno | last_type | new_billnr | id | billnr |
+-------+-----------+------------+----+--------+
|     0 | 1234      | 1234       |  2 | 1234   |
|     1 | 1234      | 1234-1     |  6 | 1234   |
|     0 | 2345      | 2345       |  5 | 2345   |
|     0 | 6789      | 6789       |  1 | 6789   |
|     1 | 6789      | 6789-1     |  3 | 6789   |
|     2 | 6789      | 6789-2     |  4 | 6789   |
+-------+-----------+------------+----+--------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [tmp]>
```